# Unwrapping optional binding fatal error

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am using latest stable Swift
inside my function i get **fatal error**.when i ran my ios app.

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value".

I searched for answer, but they offer different methods for unwrapping it.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
        var imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray[indexPath.row])
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an *if let* block to ensure the value is not nil before trying to use it

```
if let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: Thank you adding { will make it a compete solution, thanks

Comment: if you are using custom cell and populating data to custom cell's subviews ,remove    the following line                                                                                                   // Register cell classes if this is not custom class 
 self.collectionView!.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)